# Using WebApi for an existing asp.net Webforms Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I am working on an ASP.NET WebForms Application.It is a medium scale 
Accounting application.It has 4 layers consisting of Common(for POCO/Models),DataAccess(DAL),Logic(BAL),Presentation Layer(All the webform pages) and ServerControls(controls for the grid).For most of 
tasks i have been using web services.webservices in then calls the logic 
from the business layer.And i call the web methods using Ajax.It works fine.Now i want to use WebApi and have tried a bit,did some tests for 
GET and POST and it works just fine.I just wanted to know like how
should i restructure this whole project?I have like hundreds of aspx 
pages.And i have used Session in this project for storing the user_id
and office_id of the logged in users.Like i read somewhere here that
sessions arent a good idea for webapi because that makes it stateful and
not stateless.Any other alternatives?Overall expert advice on using
WebApi with webforms.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a project like this, I would create a separate project for the WebApi rather than trying to integrate it into your current site.  You can use a different port for the WebApi site, or if it's too much work to reconfigure your border security you can use host headers to select between the api site and the front end site.

As far as session, no your session will not carry over, and yes it's a bad idea anyways.  You should instead use some kind of security token, if necessary. There's all kinds of tutorials on WebApi authentication and authorization.

Comment: hello sir..how do i implement all my code behind events to the webapi controller?

Comment: @OLDMONK - I assumed you knew WHY you wanted to move to WebApi.  If you don't, I suggest you learn what it means to write WebApi code.